# Alt + Tab on Windows XP - No previews?

Tags: windows-xp, preview, alt-tab

Is there a way to get window previews like in Windows 7's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

If I have the same program open multiple times, but I'm using different parts of it, supplying only the program icon and title is useless to me.

Comment: None of the examples below are anywhere near as smooth as the win7 one, what with XP having no compositor, but they're not something I'd run an xp system without.

Answer (score 11):

[**Microsoft PowerToys for Windows XP**](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) has an [**Alt-Tab replacement**](http://download.microsoft.com/download/whistler/Install/2/WXP/EN-US/TaskswitchPowertoySetup.exe), among many other useful things:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**[TaskSwitchXP](http://www.ntwind.com/software/taskswitchxp/screenshots.html)** - Alt-Tab replacement for Windows XP. It also allows to minimize any application to the system tray instead of the taskbar.

[image]

**[WinFlip 3D](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/WinFlip.shtml)** - 'Flip 3D' function for Windows XP.

[image]

Caveat: WinFlip doesn't support video playback in 'flipped' previews (unlike Windows Vista and Windows 7).

*Both programs are free and portable; no installation is required.*

A bit off-topic, yet not unrelated: **[Visual Tooltip](http://www.chrisnsoft.com/visual-tooltip/)** will show a thumbnail preview of a window by hovering the mouse cursor over a button of the taskbar (similar to Windows Vista and Windows 7).

[image]

*Visual Tooltip is freeware.*

Comment: Regarding WinFlip3D -- if anyone has gotten bad vibes from a previous version, try out this version; it seems to be quite a bit faster than the old 0.20 version I have. Also seems to have gained a few features since the last time I tried it. It also seemed to render my five windows pretty snappy (1.8 Ghz single core proc and ATI Radeon Xpress 1150).

Comment: WinFlip 3D is indeed much smoother (especially on low end hardware) and less resource hungry than its Vista counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an [alt-tab replacement for Windows XP available here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx). It might be what you're looking for. Otherwise there are a bunch of 3rd party programs available.

Comment: you may want to edit your answer, the link points to this thread. :)

Comment: he's just showcasing my answer that's all :)

Comment: Heh yeah it looks like John T did beat me to it. And my link was broken. Oops.